# callback function and global variable in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, callback

I was using callback option to get value outside the success block(cross domain call). I am getting the value inside callback function, but not outside. please see the following code. Also if the value is available only inside callback function, then whats the difference in writing the code outside the success block.

```
var globalVar ;
        function callbackClick() {
            var jsonData = { "name": "Alex" };
            test("http://mydomain:84/AuthService.svc/TestAsyncGet", jsonData, callback);  
        }

        var callback = function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            globalVar = data;
            alert(data + "\t" + textStatus); //here I am getting data
        }

        var test = function (url, jsonData, cb) {
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processdata: true,
                success: cb,
                error: function error(response) {
                    alert("Network error");
                },
                complete: function (msg) {
                }
            });
            alert("GLOBAL  " + globalVar); //here i am not getting the value
        }
```

One more:- Even though if I didnt use callback function, the code inside success block executes before the alert statement outside $.ajax, then why I am not getting the value?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your alert after the $.ajax() instruction is executed AFTER the xmlhttprequest has started but BEFORE it has ended, i.e. before the success function is called. Thus at that time, globalVar is still undefined.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But if the alert after the $.ajax is called before the success function is called, then why the alert inside success block is firing first and I am getting the value there.